# unable to open "System > Configuration > Advanced >"

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

When i am trying to open "System > Configuration > Advanced >" Showing the following Error :

"Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have Magento `Compilation` enabled. Try after disabling it from backend.